# how do i use valgrind on xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4, valgrind

I was recommended to use valgrind for checking memory leaks at work. I'm currently compiling C++ on X-code. They use vi. I downloaded and installed the package from here: http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html

Although, now I have no idea how to use it on X-code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not just use it on the command line?

Comment: What specifically do you want to do with valgrind?  Xcode has some built-in tools that do similar things that may be easier to use.

Comment: im really new to programming (approx. 2 weeks). I'm using a lot of loops and was asked to run it through valgrind. I'm not sure how to compile on the command line. What are the valgrind substitutes on Xcode?

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Xcode has built-in tools indeed but targeted at C and Objective-C. Clang-Analyzer states "Support for analyzing C++ and Objective-C++ files is currently extremely limited". Hence the need to look for another alternative; eg: Valgrind

Source: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/dev_cxx.html

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to isolate all C++ code in standalone target, and compile it for Mac (not ios). You can continue to use xCode to write and run your code. Once your target is built, you can execute any third party command line tools, like valgrind or google test framework (from a command line, of course).